# How to add custom layouts to Rails asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using different layouts for different sections of my app. In my controller I have either:

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @orders = @user.orders.all
    render layout: 'admin'
end
```

OR

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    layout "inventory"
    #...
end
```

And in my assets I've got: `layout_theme.css.scss`, `layout_login.css.scss`, etc

And in my `views/layouts` I've got `theme.html.haml`, `login.html.haml` etc.

After making setting my app for production and using the following command to precompile the assets: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`

When I try to load the page, I get only two request for assets: `layout_theme.css` and `layout_theme.js` and an error.

I've tried adding this to my `config/application.rb`:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( layout_home.css layout_home.js layout_login.css layout_login.js layout_theme.css layout_theme.js )`

Which cover the additional files I'm using but it didn't work. What am I missing?

**EDIT: I can see the files compiled in public/assets/layout_theme...css and public/assets/layout_theme...js but it seems rails is not referencing the compiled files in the app**

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: There's no error per se apart from getting a `404` on `layout_theme.css` and `layout_theme.js` and there's not style nor js on the page.

Comment: I can see the files compiled in `public/assets/layout_theme...css` and `public/assets/layout_theme...js` but it seems rails is not referencing the compiled files in the app

Comment: How did you reference them in your views?

Comment: What's the value of `config.serve_static_assets`?

Comment: You mean in the `config/environments/production.rb` file? That's `false`

Comment: Same question stands, what's the view code that refers to them?